# Tab of Lightning Design System

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I have 2 problems:

1. I'm trying to use the tab tag in salesforce lightning : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs (i use the first one) but my tab is not responsive to the width of the browser, i need to use it in Salesforce 1 (tablette and Mobile). What should i do ?
2. In my page i have a click button to edit a record (onClick="sforce.one.editRecord("SomeID")) but when i click, i need to refresh my parent page to see the changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You might need to handle that manually (For example, in mobile you can either add a scroll or arrange tabs in a different manner if your individual tabs are very wide).
2. You can use `force:refreshView`.

Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm